# how to analyze different parameters between the two nodes in veins example of omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

in veins, the results obtained are collective of all nodes at all possible timings. is there any possible way to investigate and analyse the communication between the two nodes in the example of veins, while they are broadcasting the messages in case of an accident? like how to find packet loss between the two nodes, in the veins example of omnet++?

Comment: Here on stackoverflow it is about having clear answers to questions. You are asking two questions in one - which makes it confusing for other people when searching for answers.
Could you please move one of your questions to a separate one?

Comment: i have rectified my question i hope its more specific now. i just want to that is there any possibility of finding the results between two nodes only.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ supports two main types of data to be collected: scalars and vectors. By default, a vector is a collection of (module, statistic, event, time, value) tuples. A scalar records only (module, statistic, value) tuples, that is, it records statistics that are not associated with a particular time. In the OMNeT++ IDE, you can filter any one of these tuples before plotting, to include only certain modules, certain statistics, or (for vectors) those recorded at a particular time.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. that means only vectors statistics are important to find the parameters at particular time but the problem is packetloss and other important statistics are in the scalars section of the results. is there any vector recording of those statistics too or any way we could have those parameters in terms of time??

Comment: Most likely, for metrics that are specific to your application, you will need to add statistic collection to the appropriate modules yourself. This will ensure that you know exactly what the metric is tracking. If you are interested in what statistics are already collected in the existing modules, you can inspect the source code directly.

Comment: sir christoph sommer can you help me guide few tutorials or any reading material through which i could learn how to add the statistics and make the appropriate changes in the modules accordingly.

Comment: The OMNeT++ user manual has a large chapter on collecting data for statistics. The TicToc tutorial treats this topic as well.